# Java registering a provider throws EOFException

Tags: java, itext, eofexception

I am using `iText` to convert html to pdf and when I try to register a `fontProvider`  I get `EOFException`, here is the relevant code:

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider =new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
fontProvider.register("resources/fonts/NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf"); //this row throws the error
```

I had placed `NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf` under resources, like [iText-rtl](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-set-rtl-direction-hebrew-when-converting-html-pdf).

Here is the full code:

```
public void createPdf(String file, String htmlString) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer =
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        // Styles
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider =
            new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        fontProvider.register("resources/fonts/NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf");
        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(new FileInputStream(htmlString), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Converter test = new Converter();
    test.createPdf("C://Users//t207322//Desktop//digitalCheck//test.pdf", "C://Users//t207322//Desktop//digitalCheck//test.html");
}
```

And the stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" ExceptionConverter: java.io.EOFException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readInt(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:453)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(TrueTypeFont.java:819)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:498)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.getAllFontNames(BaseFont.java:1232)
    at com.itextpdf.text.FontFactoryImp.register(FontFactoryImp.java:451)
    at com.itextpdf.text.FontFactoryImp.register(FontFactoryImp.java:438)
    at pdf.utils.Converter.createPdf(Converter.java:110)
    at pdf.utils.Converter.main(Converter.java:218)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the path to your font `"resources/fonts/NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf` is invalid.
Try to use absolute path.

Comment: No, I had tested it and `File f = new File(PTATH_TO_TTF);  System.out.println(f.exists());` return true.